# Is it forbidden have only dynamic components in Next.js route?

Tags: next.js

Got this error:

```
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/71)Invalid href passed to next/router: /undefined/undefined//undefined, repeated forward-slashes (//) or backslashes \ are not valid in the href
```

Yes, created a route, where there is not static part.

pages / [organizationShortId] / [postId] / [tempUserShortId] / [imgId] / index.tsx

But never 4 undefined is sent as error indicate. Strange. Plotting data which is retured in `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`.

```
info  - Collecting page data .[
  [ 'kubl', 'jhze', 'onla', 'd1fd284e-b27a-4c2b-9d39-c8dccc2f2f6b' ],
  [ 'kubl', 'jhze', 'a405', '5c22abac-8bea-4229-a2ed-70e81813c359' ],
  [ 'kubl', 'jhze', 'gw76', 'eec549c0-829a-401a-bd65-118bf36736ce' ],
  [ 'kubl', 'ib89', 'gw76', 'd0967831-0f31-4161-ae53-c37a1a924e3e' ]
]
{
  paths: [
    { params: [Object] },
    { params: [Object] },
    { params: [Object] },
    { params: [Object] }
  ],
  fallback: true
}
info  - Collecting page data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, pass `na` string, during hidration:

```js
<Link href={`/${organizationShortId ?? 'na'}/${postId ?? 'na'}/${tempUserShortId ?? 'na'}/${po?.imgId1}`}>{`${origin}/${organizationShortId}/${postId}/${tempUserShortId}/${po?.imgId1}`}</Link>
```

One possible cause:

You are using template literals to define your href (href={`/posts/${postName}/comments} for example).

If you are setting this postName variable after hydration or in a useEffect and the default is an empty string ('') this will lead to repeated forward-slashes in the href until the variable has been updated.